PHP-FPM not working in Docker Compose due to "NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms" notice
I'm encountering an issue with PHP-FPM in my Docker Compose setup. When I run docker-compose up, PHP-FPM starts, but I receive the following notice in the logs:
[05-Apr-2024 09:38:31] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
After this notice, PHP-FPM doesn't seem to be functioning correctly, and my application is not working as expected.
Here's some context about my setup:
I'm using Docker Compose to manage my application's containers.
PHP-FPM is being used to handle PHP requests.
The notice appears in the PHP-FPM container's logs after it starts up.
My application relies on PHP-FPM to process PHP scripts.
I've tried looking for solutions online, but I haven't found a clear answer to resolve this issue. How can I troubleshoot and resolve the "NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms" notice and ensure that PHP-FPM works correctly in my Docker Compose setup?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

That message seems unusual, since I'd almost never expect systemd to be running inside a container.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?
